# Write a program in python to check whether a given matrix forms magic square or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, matrix-multiplication, magic-square

A basket is given to you in the shape of a matrix. If the size of the matrix is N x N then the range of number of eggs you can put in each slot of the basket is 1 to N2 . You task is to arrange the eggs in the basket such that the sum of each row, column and the diagonal of the matrix remain same.
Test case for your reference:
Input by the user dimension of the basket i.e., N = 3
So, number of eggs you can put at each slot are in the range of 1 to 32 (1 to 9)
Input:
6 3 6
5 5 5
4 7 4

I am expecting a python code to check if a matrix forms a magic square or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("WELCOME! SIR I AM MATHEMAGIX PROGRAM. \n I WILL CHECK AND TELL YOU IF YOU CAN ARRANGE THE EGGS IN THE BASKET IN THAT MANNER OR NOT.")
print("\n")
print("MAGIC SQUARE :- [A square divided into smaller squares each containing a number,\n                 such that the figures in each vertical, horizontal, and diagonal row add up to the same value.]")
print("\n")
n=int(input("ENTER THE SIZE OF SQUARE MATRIX SHAPED BASKET YOU HAVE: "))
print("\n")
print("ENTER THE NO. OF EGGS BELOW, WHICH YOU WANT IN EACH SECTION OF THE BASKET.")
print("\n")
a=[]
for i in range (n):
    b=[]
    for j in range (n):
        j=int(input("Enter The Number of EGGS = "))  
        b.append(j)
    a.append(b)
if j<=(n*n):
    print("\n")
    print("THE BASKET ARRANGEMENT is ......")
    print("\n")
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range (n):
            print(a[i][j],end=" ")
        print()
    sum1d=0
    sum2d=0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i==j:
                sum1d=sum1d+a[i][j]
            if i+j==n-1:
                sum2d=sum2d+a[i][j]
    if sum1d!=sum2d:
        z=5
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            sumr=0
            sumc=0
            for j in range(n):
                sumr=sumr+a[i][j]
                sumc=sumc+a[j][i]
            if sumr!=sum1d:
                z=1
            elif sumc!=sum1d:
                z=1
            else:
                z=0
    if z==0:
        print("\n")
        print("YES SIR! YOU CAN ARRANGE YOUR BASKET WITH THE EGGS IN THAT MANNER.\nIT WILL RESULT IN FORMING A MAGIC SQUARE.")
    else:
        print("\n")
        print("UH OH! SORRY SIR YOU CAN'T ARRANGE YOUR EGGS LIKE THAT! \nIT DOESN'T FORM A MAGIC SQUARE.")
else:
    print("\n")
    print("THE NO. OF EGGS ENTERED IN ANY SLOT HAS MORE VALUE/VALUES GREATER THAN n².(i.e.- OVER THE CAPACITY OF THAT SLOT OF THE BASKET.)\n PLEASE RE-RUN THE PROGRAM AND RE-ENTER THE VALUES OF NO. OF EGGS PROPERLY !")
```